# Non-updated value of getSelectedButtonID from RecyclerView adapter to main script

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView that displays two views. I want that the text, of the second view, changes depending on the selected Material Button from the first view. Kinda like a tab system but without the tabs and fragments. So far, the recyclerView adapter sends through an interface, I feel like, the same ID as the application is only capable of detecting when I'm touching the first button of the togglegroup and not the others. It is not updating the ID of the selected button. Right now, I really don't see where I've failed.

Is it because the adapter is not being updated? I tried to update it in the getTabs() function but I can't call adapter.notifyDataChanged() since "adapter" belongs to the createRecyclerView() function.

I tried to call the onClick method in the onBindViewHolder method but I can't set the selected button ID to the togglegroupID (which is based of "getSelectedButtonID") since itemview is not part of the onBindViewHolder function.

I've read my code so many times now and can't find the error...

my RecyclerView Adapter script:

```
public class act_main_recycler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

\...
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        MaterialButtonToggleGroup Tabs;
        MaterialButton Prn_Btn;
        OnButtonListener onButtonListener;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnButtonListener onButtonListener) {
            super(itemView);
            Tabs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup);
            this.onButtonListener = onButtonListener;
            int toggleGroupID = Tabs.getCheckedButtonId();
            Prn_Btn = itemView.findViewById(toggleGroupID);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            Prn_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (onButtonListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        int ID = Prn_Btn.getId();
                        onButtonListener.ontabClick(position, ID);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

public interface OnButtonListener{
        void onButtonClick (int position);
        void ontabClick(int position, int ID);
    }

}
```

My Main code :

```
public class act_main extends AppCompatActivity implements act_main_recycler_adapter.OnButtonListener{


    private ArrayList<String> Texts = new ArrayList<>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_act_main);
        Texts.add("+65.1");
        createRecyclerView();
    }
private void createRecyclerView(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Recycler_View);
        act_main_recycler_adapter adapter = new act_main_recycler_adapter(this, Texts,this );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
private void getTabs(int ID){
        switch (ID){
            case R.id.principale:
                Texts.set(0, "+65.1");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Principales" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            case R.id.audio:
                Texts.set(0, "+21.5");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Audio" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            case R.id.visuels:
                Texts.set(0, "39.5");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Visuels" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            default:
                Texts.set(0, "Paramètres");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Paramètres" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void ontabClick(int position, int ID) {
        getTabs(ID);
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:checkedButton="@+id/principale"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/principale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Principale"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:elevation="5dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/audio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Audio"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:elevation="5dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/visuels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Visuels"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:elevation="5dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now, the only thing working in the getTabs() function is the first case as the Toast message "Principales" is correctly being displayed on the app. This is not the same for the other cases, nothing is being displayed.

How can I fix this? How can I update the text of the second view since I can't call adapter.notifyDataChanged() outside the createRecyclerView() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of using Tabs.getCheckedId (Which totally works) and call upon a button (which will remain the same button since you can't update it), you have to add a listener to the togglegroup and work from there. The modified code looks like this.

Change the ViewHolder to this:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        MaterialButtonToggleGroup Tabs;
        MaterialButton Prn_Btn;
        OnButtonListener onButtonListener;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnButtonListener onButtonListener) {
            super(itemView);
            Tabs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup);
            this.onButtonListener = onButtonListener;
            int toggleGroupID = Tabs.getCheckedButtonId();
            Prn_Btn = itemView.findViewById(toggleGroupID);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            Tabs.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (onButtonListener != null){
                        if (isChecked){
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            onButtonListener.ontabClick(position, checkedId);
                        }
                        if (Tabs.getCheckedButtonId() == -1){
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            onButtonListener.ontabClick(position, -1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```